# String to Char Array and Char array to String Conversion

Tags: java

In my program I am getting a string from Database result set and convert it to char array like this:

```
emp.nid = rs.getString("nid").toCharArray();
```

In this part there is no error. The String is successfully converted to char array.
But I have another code like this:

```
nid_txt.setText(emp.nid.toString());
```

This prints some freaky text. Not the original. Why was this happens? Please help me.

Comment: If you had read the toString() method description you would've figured this out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `toString` on a `char[]` - and that inherits the implementation from `Object`, so you get the `char[].class` name, @ and then the hash of the object. Instead, call the `String(char[])` constructor:

```
nid_txt.setText(new String(emp.nid));
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the `toString()` method is the String representation of the object, and not the String of what it contains.

Try doing like this:

```
nid_txt.setText(new String(emp.nid));
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `foo.toString()` do `new String(foo)`.

Comment: If it's helpful, you should vote it up :-) and accept most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the toString() on the array object. Try:

```
new String(emp.nid);
```

and you should see better results.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that emp.nid is byte array second sentence is completely wrong. toString() method in such object won't work. Try insted creating new String based on byte array:

```
String s = new String(emp.nid);
nid_txt.setText(s);
```